# Query condition where a value is in a comma separated string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in which one of the table columns `third_row` stores a comma-separated list of numbers as a string but when its value is `A` then it means a combination of all the possible numbers. How do I approach this so that the query returns all the rows that have the `third_row` as `A` and the rest where `third_row` is equal to one of the values in the comma-separated string?

For reference, here is the format of the table:

| first_row | second_row | third_row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0028001070200 | 50 | A |
| 0049048000701 | 51 | 01,04,02,31, |

I have also tried this query but no luck:

```
SELECT
    sds.scheme_code,
    rs.scheme_name
FROM
trea.salary_deduction_schemes sds
LEFT JOIN
trea.receipt_schemes rs
ON sds.scheme_code = rs.scheme_code
WHERE sds.list_object_head = 'A'
OR 16 IN(regexp_split_to_table(sds.list_object_head, E','))
```

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: I would have preferred to use another table to map these integers but it's an old project that started way before I joined.

Comment: That's a programmer's life, struggling with other peoples' poor designs.

Comment: `WHERE sds.list_object_head = 'A' or 16 = any(string_to_array(sds.list_object_head, ',')::integer[])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method almost works:

```
WHERE sds.list_object_head = 'A' OR
      16 IN (SELECT val::int
             FROM regexp_split_to_table(sds.list_object_head, E',') val
            )
```

You can also use string matching:

```
WHERE ',' || sds.list_object_head || ',' LIKE '%,' || 16 || ',%'
```

Or you could convert to an array and use array operations.

I would strongly suggest that find a representation other than strings for storing *integer* values -- preferably another table or perhaps an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to an array and use the `= any` operator:

```
WHERE sds.list_object_head = 'A' 
   OR 16 = any(string_to_array(trim(',' from sds.list_object_head), ',')::int[])
```

The `trim()` is necessary to get rid of the trailing `,` that would result in an empty string after applying `string_to_array()` and that in turn would result in a casting error as an empty string isn't a valid integer.

This is probably a bit faster than using a regex and unnesting the array.